# Clear-TcmPublicationTarget failing with a timeout

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager, powershell, sql-server

I am receiving a SQL time out when trying to use the `Clear-TcmPublicationTarget` command in Powershell.

Has anybody seen this before and knows how to fix it?

[image: Error]

Comment: sp_updatestats is currently running - hopefully that will sort it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds a lot like database maintenance is lacking, for MS SQL Server you can use the following command:

```
exec sp_updatestats;
```

This updates the statistics of the databaase which usually solves performance problems (like timeouts on queries). Now for SQL Server updating the statistics can be configured to be run automatically, but that doesn't always run at the time it needs to. A proper DBA will manually schedule database maintenance at fixed time ensuring it always runs. SOmething Oracle DBAs have to do anyways.

If the update stats did not solve your probblem, and we are talking about MS SQL Server, the next step is to look at your DB configuration. SQL Server is notorious for becoming slow if the transaction log is turned on and not regularly trunkated (after it was backed up ;o). On developer machine I often turn off the transaction log feature, since I don't have the knowledge how to restore it anyways, so it is just slowing my server down. A traansaction log size of larger than 1GB usually means your DB will be too slow for decent queries, so you need to fix that.

Comment: sp_updatestats didn't work :-/ We're still investigating other ideas. May need to raise a support case.

Comment: Check the transaction log size, or turn off and shrink DB if possible

Comment: Turns out the databases had been set up wrong (tempdb, transactionlog and data all on the same drive)

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same above issue for one of our customer environment today, We did watch the timeout value by mobile stopwatch, and noticed it was getting timing out by 55 seconds.

We also tried the **sp_updatestats** not helped. then we increased the timeout settings value in SDL Console for ***" seconds before a timeout error is generated when executing a query"*** from **50** to **180** and restarted the following services then timeout issue gone for us and **Clear-TcmPublicationTarget** cmdlet command was got success.

- IIS Reset
- SDL Com+ services
- SDL Service Host

[image]